# InnoDB: Error: log sequence number is in the future!

Tags: mysql, mariadb, recovery, galera

Hi I have 2 node cluster where recently went offline not sure why. Node1 started fine and all the traffic is on node 1 but node 2 still down due to below error. I tried set the inodb recovery to 3 and start but i cant start and the same error as like below. I've even tried removing the "aria file, Galera cache,gwstate file" and restart MySQL but still the same error.

How can i get the node 2 started or should i do full resync.

```
7a0d83860019dca40019dca30019dca500000b8b15ef4dad45bf0000000000000000000000be000d3b21803500000000180615 12:13:14  InnoDB: Error: page 1209437 log sequence number 12729899042363
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 12692016003988.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try a full resync, i.e. SST, at this point.

Note that depending on your `wsrep_sst_method` (see [description MariaDB knowledgebase](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/galera-cluster-system-variables/#wsrep_sst_method)) an SST may block the donor node (node1 in this case) while it's making the backup. The default `wsrep_sst_method` is `rsync`, which is blocking.

You should in theory be able to force an SST by removing the `grastate.dat` file from the datadir and then restart MariaDB, but I'm unsure if that works in your case. So if that doesn't work, then you could proceed as if you were adding a new node to the cluster. In this case, basically just wipe the datadir, run `mysql_install_db`, and try starting up the new node.

Comment: i did try removing the grastate.dat and restart mysql but it fails with the same error. Your suggestion like adding as if new node to the pool, should i remove /var/lib/mysql and run mysql_install_db. So can ia lso assume the data sync will happen by itself or should i copy over the ibdata from node 1?

btw our  wsrep_sst_method = rsync

Comment: Remove everything inside the datadir, but I think the directory itself must exist with the correct ownership and permissions when you run mysql_install_db. The SST should then happen automatically when MariaDB is started.

Comment: does this require a maintenance window like stopping the mysql on first node from doing insert. On top of it can i just run mysql_install_db upon me deleting the files in /var/lib/mysql.

Comment: @Deva Yes, becase rsync will block it. If you were using a different `wsrep_sst_method` such as `mariabackup` or `xtrabackup-v2`, then it shouldn't block except for a very short while.